# Invalid status code when using node, express and mysql package to add new user to mysql db

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a crud API using nodeJS, so far I want to make a POST request and add a new user to the database. I am able to successfully add a new user to the db, however right after I upload a user to the db my server crashes.

This is the code that I have for the POST request:

```
`app.post('/new/user', (req, res) => {
    const data = {id: req.body.id, name: req.body.name, status: req.body.status }
    console.log("------>>>",req.body.id)

    const newUser = `INSERT INTO users (id, name, status) VALUES('${data.id}', '${data.name}', '${data.status}')`;

    connection.query(newUser, data, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw(err)
        res.send(result, console.log('added new user successfully'));
    });
});


`
```

And this the error I get,

```
added new user sucessfully
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead index.js:47:13
/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:275:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:266:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:871:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:232:10)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/index.js:47:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/guilherme/Projects/MeetingHandler2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}`
```

Please note the user actually gets added to the db with no problem/ the only problem is that then crashes my local server. Thanks in advance for any solutions and insights!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I actually managed to solve it myself by removing the result from the connection.query function. I believe the reason it was angry was because the result could only be a string and I was sending an object(However Im not sure if that the cause), but yeah when I took it out now I can add a user without crashing the server. Cheers

Comment: Go ahead and mark it as answered if it solved your problem.